# How can I show more than the last 3 commits?

Tags: git

`git log` shows only last 3 commit though i have more-than 50 commit.

`git log -10` still shows only last 3 commits.

How can i increase the commit limits?

Comment: Did you happen to clone this repository as a shallow copy?

Comment: yes i have done shallow clone

Comment: Shallow clones only copy the last commit. git log shows only commits that are available at the cloned repository.

Comment: You may want to find the log for origin/HEAD. I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shallow copies only carry over the commit log depth you configured when you cloned the repository.

If you want to update your shallow copy with a deeper commit history, run:

```
git fetch --depth=<number-of-commits>
```

If you want to unshallow this repository and get the full history from the remote, run:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

*Note: Unshallowing your repo may take a while and will result in a bigger repository size. Usually teams recommend cloning shallow copies for a reason.*

Answer (score 1):

`git log` should display all the commits you have.

check to see if you have any alias which limit your commit.
To check it print out the git aliases you have and check for the log alias.

```
# print out aliases
git config -l


# The right answer to display last 10 commits is:
git commit -n 10

# display how many commits you have in your repo:
git rev-list --all --count
```

Comment: still it shows only 3 with the above command yes I do have alias

Comment: where can i see the limit? Iam using bitbucket

Comment: updated the answer with command to display total number of commits in your repo.if the output of this command is still 3 it means that you did not cloned the full repository. (have you cloned with --depth)?

Comment: `git rev-list --all --count` shows 65 and no I have done shallow clone

Comment: so you have 65 commits, have you checked your aliases?